# Python, loop of statements pulling from excel

Tags: python, excel, loops

Im still new to python. Just wondering if there is an easier way to accomplish my task.

This is my current code

```
win = visual.Window([800,800],monitor="testmonitor", units="deg")

msg = visual.TextStim(win, text='hello this is a test',pos=[0,+1],color='white')
msg.draw()
win.flip()
core.wait(2)

msg = visual.TextStim(win, text='statement 1',pos=[0,+1],color='white')
msg.draw()
win.flip()
core.wait(2)

msg = visual.TextStim(win, text='statement 2',pos=[0,+1],color='white')
msg.draw()
win.flip()
core.wait(2)

msg = visual.TextStim(win, text='statement 3',pos=[0,+1],color='white')
msg.draw()
win.flip()
core.wait(2)
```

Is there a way I can pull statements from an excel file?

For example:
I would have a loop going on and each round it would pull the next line in the file instead of having to copy the code and write a new statement each time?

Comment: [```xlrd```](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) for actual Excel files or the [```csv```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module for *csv* text files.  You could also put all the strings in a [```list```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) (or other container) and iterate over it.

Answer (score 2):

> [**D** on't
>
>   **R** epeat
>
>   **Y** ourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Your solution uses 4 blocks of codes of 4 lines each, the last 3 lines are the same, and the first is almost the same too!

You can avoid this by using a loop, as you guessed.

Look at what changes between each of your blocks, and stores it in a tuple (for example). Then, loop through this tuple and apply the block with the variable element.

```
texts = (
    'hello this is a test',
    'statement 1',
    'statement 2',
    'statement 3'
)

for text in texts:
    msg = visual.TextStim(win, text=text, pos=[0, +1], color='white')
    msg.draw()
    win.flip()
    core.wait(2)
```